# How to track down Facebook notifications on OS X to disable them

Tags: macos, notifications

I have a Macbook Air running OS X 10.11/El Capitan and two days ago these notification just started appearing:

[image]

Perhaps I hit some special keys accidentally, but I want it to go away and it won't.  Furthermore, I have NO facebook option in my Notifications:

[image]

Safari:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

**How do I stop this?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What application is in the foreground when the notification window arrives? Can you move that notification to another screen (Mission Control style) or is it rendered entirely within a web browser window - perhaps in Safari?

Comment: @bmike Chrome appears to be in the foreground, but I am not certain on this point.  But as you can see, Chrome's notifications are suppose to be disabled.

Comment: Basically, notifications mean that the app (Chrome or whatever) hands off something that you can block on the OS level. If it's just pictures rendering in the frame of the browser, you'll need to break javascript / content blocker to prevent the web app from drawing what "looks" like a window. For example - see http://chocklock.com - the ants and spinners are just animations being rendered within the page and not something the OS or notification settings can block.

Comment: @bmike I don't have any facebook extensions/plugins in Chrome - what on Earth would do this without user's permission?  And I am not in facebook.

Comment: I'm trying to get you to tell us if you are dealing with a normal web page popup - like https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/north-korea-says-it-has-conducted-a-successful-hydrogen-bomb-test/2016/01/06/9add0e52-b436-11e5-a76a-0b5145e8679a_story.html?hpid=hp_hp-top-table-main_nkoreatest-2am%3Ahomepage%2Fstory or if it's really a "window" that can be moved outside the web page. No user permission is needed to render within the page or even open many types of pop up windows.

Comment: @bmike  I think it's an OS pop up.

Comment: In Chrome, hit that `Manage exceptions...` button. See [Turn off and Disable Facebook Notifications in Google Chrome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdaP1SzWs0E) (a Youtube video).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manage exceptions, check that in the chrome

Comment: I don't know how a facebook entry would have been created, but that was likely that cause.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Check Safari prefs too, as Facebook is not an app, but a web-based service…

[image]

Comment: Only CNN in there and it's denied - They are also disabled in Chrome.

Comment: My supposition is that this isn't an OS notification at all. I'm trying to get clarification in the comments of the question - most likely it's javascript rendering the "notification" window as part of DOM/CSS/layout and that the web app settings need to be changed or a content blocker deployed to remove that one aspect of the rendered page...